# Sign-In Required [Environment: Sandbox]

Tags: ios, signing

I am a developer and sometimes I use my phone to develop in - app purchases using my own account.

But now I have finished my in - app purchases. The app is in app store, but almost every day there appears popup on the screen like this:

[image]

Why it happens? What to do to turn it off? I don't need it anymore.

Comment: Sign out from settings app(iTunes section).

Comment: But I dont wanna sign out. This is my real apple id.

Comment: Remove the app and reinstall